# Creating attributes for elements of a PCollection in Apache Beam

Tags: apache-beam

I'm fairly new to Apache Beam and was wondering if I can create my own attributes for elements in a PCollection.
I went through the docs but could not find anything.

Example 2 in [this ParDo doc](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/elementwise/pardo/) shows how to access the `TimestampParam` and the `WindowParam`, which are - from what I understand - attributes of each element in a PCollection:

```py
class AnalyzeElement(beam.DoFn):
  def process(
      self,
      elem,
      timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam,
      window=beam.DoFn.WindowParam):
      yield [...]
```

So my question is, if it is possible to create such attributes (e.g. TablenameParam) for the elements in a PCollection and if not, if there is some kind of workaround to achieve that?

Comment: A [PCollection](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pcollections) is a multi-element dataset. For this, you need to know that a dataset is a file that contains one or more records; in other words, a dataset corresponds to one or more database tables. The example from the link that you passed the TimestampParam and WindowParam are not in a PCollection, these only bring information from the object that is binded. The `ParDo` function can filter the Dataset, format types, and extract parts of elements.

Comment: Can you please provide more specific information about what you want to achieve?  Maybe what you are looking for is to apply a [transform](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#applying-transforms) to your PCollection.

Comment: Yes I understand that the TimestampParam is not in the PCollection. One could say it is meta information of an element in the PCollection, right? So I want to give more meta information like that to the elements in my PCollection, for example a TablenameParam that tells the table where the information of the element should be written to at the end of the pipeline. I hope this makes it more clear what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing would simply be part of the element. For your example, the `TablenameParam` would be a field of the type you add to the PCollection.

The reason that `WindowParam` and `TimestampParam` are treated differently is that they are often propagated implicitly, and are a part of the Beam model for *every* element no matter the actual data. Most code that is only operating on the main data does not need to touch them.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. After working more with Beam and I guess I understand it better. Just to be sure I don't miss an opportunity to learn, did you mean a specific *type* in the sentence '[...] would be a field of the type you add to the PCollection.'? I would just assume a string.